# How to set default value of function string parameter to empty in Visual Studio 2013 UML class diagram designer?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, uml, class-diagram, class-designer

I want to setup function parameter setting in Visual Studio 2013 UML class diagram designer that result something like this code

```
public void Execute(string query = "")
    {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Operation properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjbfA.png)

Generated method looks like

```
public virtual void Execute(string query = "")
{
    throw new System.NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: This is the generated code public static IEnumerable<T> Read(string query = """"), and I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate version 12.0.40629

Comment: parameter type is string not String

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is called an optional argument (in C#, at least). The original documentation is pretty good on this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) but the gist of it is

```
public void Execute(int num, string optionalstr = "")
```

By doing this, `num` is required, and `optionalstr` is used if it is given, otherwise defaults to the right side of the equals, in this case: an empty string.

Comment: bro I know how to code optional argument, I want To model string optional parameter with visual studio 2015 class diagram designer